# Sources of free European national income and output data?

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request

What are good free sources of European National income and output data?

By this I mean, amongst others: 
`GDP` and the variations of this such as; `GNP, GNI, NNI` and similar.

Preferable in english and with formats that are easy to work with, such as `.xls, .csv, .sdv.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annual macro-economic database of the European Commission (AMECO) provides the data you need.

The data is available for free, in formats that are easy to work with.

Comment: http://ec.europa.eu/economy_finance/db_indicators/ameco/index_en.htm